# run certain code at specific times (time interrupts ? )

Tags: c++

What would be the best way to run certain code (c++ cross-platform) at specific intervals :

for example :

- run code block 1 each second
- run code block 2 each 5 seconds
- run code block 3 every 3600 seconds

This whole application should run as a service (windows/linux) and while not executing certain code blocks it should execute other code also.

Comment: What is wrong with cron?

Comment: you mean this one?

https://github.com/PerMalmberg/libcron

Seems like what I was searching for. 
Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: You can use an asynchronous periodic timer in Boost Asio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267546/c-boost-asio-simple-periodic-timer